# can we construct a binary tree with singly linked list

Tags: data-structures

I have googled a lot and none of them showed how to create a binary tree with singly linked list.
Is it even possible to create one ?! I remember that I Have read somewhere that Binary trees can be created using singly linked list.

Comment: is it that u just want to store the binary tree in a linked list or u want to perform all the operations like traversal addition/deletion on it too???

Comment: I just need to parse through all the nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [represent a binary tree as an array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). If the only direction you want to go in your tree is root-to-leaf, then you could, in theory, use a singly linked list instead of the array.

This would result, however, in a **huge** performance loss as you will have to go pointer chasing instead of just jumping directly to the next node, as you do in an array.

I find it hard to think of a scenario where you would actually do that, but its possible in principle.